# How to extract first letters of words in a string in ruby without looping?

Tags: ruby, string

I have tried to get first letters of words of a string using ruby. the following is what i have written.

```
puts "world is a better place".split.collect{|w| w[0].capitalize}.join()
```

Is there a much more concise way of producing the same result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using regular expression:

```
"world is a better place".scan(/\b[a-z]/i).join
# => "wiabp"
"world is a better place".scan(/\b[a-z]/i).join.upcase
# => "WIABP"
```

`\b` matches word boundary. (between word character and non-word character). `[a-z]` match any alphabet.

`\b[a-z]` matches the first alphabet letter of word.

**NOTE** Above code will not work if there's a word(?) that starts with non-alphabet character. Also does not work if there's a word that contains a punctuation in it. (For example: `World is 1 better-place.`)

**UPDATE**

Using [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) with capturing group you will get the same result:

```
"world is a better place".gsub(/\s*(\S)\S*/, '\1').upcase
# => "WIABP"
```

Comment: NOTE As well as if there is a word that has a space or hyphen in it.

Comment: @sawa, Thank you for pointing that. I added that to the NOTE. Also added an alternative solution.